# How to access and copy Cloudian S3 files using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, file-copying, access-keys

I'm new to AWS S3. I need to access a Cloudian S3 bucket and copy files within a bucket to my local directory. What I was given was 4 piece of info in the following format:

```
•   Access key: 5x4x3x2x1xxx
•   Secret key: ssssssssssss
•   S3 endpoint: https://s3-aaa.xxx.bbb.net
•   Storage path: store/STORE1/
```

When I'm trying to do a simple command like `ls`, I get this error:

`aws s3 ls s3-aaa.xxx.bbb.net` or `aws s3 ls https://s3-aaa.xxx.bbb.net`:

```
An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

What is the right commands to access the bucket and copy a file to my local directory?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing your bucket name - you should be able to see it on the AWS S3 console.
You should also be able to use either the `cp` or `sync` command like so:

```
aws s3 cp s3://SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME/s3/file/key SomeDrive:/path/to/my/local/directory
```

Or:

```
aws s3 sync s3://SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME/s3/file/key SomeDrive:/path/to/my/local/directory
```

You may also need to check the permissions on the s3 bucket.

More info:
aws s3 sync: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

aws s3 cp: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

aws s3 permissions: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-access-default-encryption/

Comment: Is bucket name that storage path `store/STORE1/`? And what is the `SomeDrive`? And given access key and secret key, what other permission do I need?

Comment: Let's do this one step at a time. If you first log into the AWS console on aws.com, then click on services, and select S3, you will be taken to the S3 dashboard where you can see your list of s3-buckets. The `SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME` above refers to the name of the bucket as it appears on the dashboard. Can you find your bucket?

Comment: Well, I know what you mean. Thanks. But the thing is I didn't create this bucket so it's not my dashboard. These information are not from my personal account. I just need to get some files from it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Without the bucket name I am not sure how you would access the bucket content from AWS CLI. A quick search online didn't provide anything promising.

Comment: Yes. I think that storage path is the bucket name.

Comment: Ok, then assuming the bucket name is in the storage path, you can try the copy command like so: `aws s3 cp s3://store/Store1/file1 /path/to/local/directory/file1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208073/discussion-between-daniel-and-tina-j).